# Apply a different format to a part of the document only

Tags: formatting

I want the subsection body starting in the same line as subsection name for only one chapter in my thesis document. If I try the following code, the entire document gets effected.

```
\usepackage{titlesec} 

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please explain why you want to change the style of subsections for a single chapter only? Wouldn't this make the formatting of your document somewhat inconsistent?

Comment: Please also make your example code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). Are your subsubsections numbered? If not, why not use a `\paragraph` for `runin` ones instead?

Comment: `titleformat` can be used locally, inside the body of the document